# Inserir uma mesma imagem várias vezes através da input file

Tags: javascript, html, imagem, arquivo, input

Estou montando um site de uma escola, e estou adotando um novo recurso. Criei uma input file para as pessoas inserirem imagens e elas, através de um preview devem aparacer nos respectivos quadros que há abaixo. Porém ela só funciona com o primeiro quadro! não cai nos outros três.

**Este é o link que podem ver e entender:** http://escolacem.com.br/painel/index-bilhete.php

O meu código está da seguinte forma:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)

            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /> <img id="blah" class="largura" />
```

Como faço para a imagem aparecer mais vezes nos outros quadros?

Comment: Como está essa área dos quadros? `$('#blah')
                    .attr` sugere somente um elemento.

Comment: voce esta pegando somente o primeiro arquivo `input.files[0]` - lembrando que o `id` das suas `img` devem ser únicos. entao voce poderia adicionar `blah` como uma class e selecionar as imagens pela class `blah`